# How to do Simple video streaming with ffserver on windows?

Tags: windows, video, streaming, webcam, ffserver

I found a tutorial for configuring server here http://www.organicdesign.co.nz/Simple_video_streaming_with_ffserver

but it is for linux... how to do such thing on windows? (with a real web cam)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont think ffserver exists on windows, my suggestion is to set up a linux box(ubuntu?) and play with ffserver there :)

Comment: While ffmpeg can be compiled on windows, ffserver, which is the main component being discussed, cannot be compiled on/for Windows... I'd be very happy if someone proved me wrong about this tho.

Answer (score 1):

Although, I too have read, in older posts, that builds for Windows are non-existing, this morning I found (not me, but google) this blog: https://www.virag.si/2012/11/streaming-live-webm-video-with-ffmpeg/

Comes with a small guide also!

But as an alternative to ffserver, I would recommend [rtmplite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) (you need python, but is extremely easy to use - at least in dev), or if you have java experience and alot of patience and time, [red5](http://www.red5.org/)!

Answer (score 0):

download and install ICECAST server. It works for windows and ffmpeg and lets you live stream a video in mp4 and webm which you can publish and showcase online with html and php. Its the easiest way. I wish someone had told me this but I had to figure this out, thru trial and error. If this doesn't work for you type live stream server software on google search engine.  http://icecast.org/ code that should configure it with ffmpeg https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/icecast_8c_source.html. ffserver does no work for windows and its a huge waste of time.